# Node.js app not working on Azure App Service

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, express, azure-web-app-service

I am new to Azure and trying to deploy my first node js app on Azure App Service. I need help i followed some videos and blogs with Mircosft but i don't know why my app is not working i followed every step.

In my azure protal i can see my project but when i open that URL it just load and load you can see from here https://test-azure-app-node.azurewebsites.net/. when i open logs i can see these logs.

Also after loading it shows this error :( Application Error If you are the application administrator, you can access the

index.js:

```
import express from 'express'

const port = 80;
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello World");
})

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello, Azure")
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server Is Running On Port", port)
})
```

```
2023-11-04T12:11:09 Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.

Starting Log Tail -n 10 of existing logs ----/home/LogFiles/__lastCheckTime.txt (https://test-azure-app-node.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/\__lastCheckTime.txt)11/04/2023 12:11:01/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/5d8620c911f4-ff0d338d-0294-41de-aa40-0539f407d121.txt (https://test-azure-app-node.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/5d8620c911f4-ff0d338d-0294-41de-aa40-0539f407d121.txt)

2023-11-04T12:11:08 Startup Request, url: /api/logstream/, method: GET, type: request, pid: 87,1,7, ScmType: None, SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT: true/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/efb0ffaae9f5-2e38a9e3-146d-472e-b1e0-577cf788e916.txt (https://test-azure-app-node.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/efb0ffaae9f5-2e38a9e3-146d-472e-b1e0-577cf788e916.txt)

2023-11-04T10:47:34 Startup Request, url: /api/zipdeploy?author=ms-azuretools-vscode&deployer=ms-azuretools-vscode&isAsync=true&trackDeploymentId=true, method: POST, type: request, pid: 86,1,14, ScmType: None, SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT: true/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/efb0ffaae9f5-3a2aa2e0-6a23-478e-9d66-a0b5fcada6f1.txt (https://test-azure-app-node.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/efb0ffaae9f5-3a2aa2e0-6a23-478e-9d66-a0b5fcada6f1.txt)

2023-11-04T10:52:19 Outgoing response, type: response, statusCode: 404, statusText: NotFound

/home/LogFiles/2023_11_04_10-30-8-107_default_docker.log (https://test-azure-app-node.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2023_11_04_10-30-8-107_default_docker.log)/home/LogFiles/2023_11_04_10-30-8-107_docker.log (https://test-azure-app-node.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2023_11_04_10-30-8-107_docker.log)

2023-11-04T12:08:40.147Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container test-azure-app-node_0_ce91ac8a. Elapsed time = 30.4170664 sec

2023-11-04T12:08:55.292Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container test-azure-app-node_0_ce91ac8a. Elapsed time = 45.5615917 sec

2023-11-04T12:09:10.891Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container test-azure-app-node_0_ce91ac8a. Elapsed time = 61.1614305 sec

2023-11-04T12:09:28.400Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container test-azure-app-node_0_ce91ac8a. Elapsed time = 78.6696169 sec

2023-11-04T12:09:43.516Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container test-azure-app-node_0_ce91ac8a. Elapsed time = 93.7857253 sec

2023-11-04T12:09:58.622Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container test-azure-app-node_0_ce91ac8a. Elapsed time = 108.891784 sec

2023-11-04T12:10:13.752Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container test-azure-app-node_0_ce91ac8a. Elapsed time = 124.0219563 sec

2023-11-04T12:10:29.912Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container test-azure-app-node_0_ce91ac8a. Elapsed time = 140.182153 sec

2023-11-04T12:10:45.016Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container test-azure-app-node_0_ce91ac8a. Elapsed time = 155.2862329 sec

2023-11-04T12:11:00.116Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container test-azure-app-node_0_ce91ac8a. Elapsed time = 170.3854777 sec/home/LogFiles/2023_11_04_10-30-8-108_default_docker.log (https://test-azure-app-node.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2023_11_04_10-30-8-108_default_docker.log)

2023-11-04T11:55:36.000783266Z npm info using npm@9.6.4

2023-11-04T11:55:36.001987940Z npm info using node@v18.17.1

2023-11-04T11:55:36.067716235Z

2023-11-04T11:55:36.067759637Z > app@1.0.0 start

2023-11-04T11:55:36.067768438Z > node index.js

2023-11-04T11:55:36.067773738Z

2023-11-04T11:55:36.596291661Z Server Is Running On Port 3000

2023-11-04T11:55:36.779423492Z npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm 730ms (cache updated)

2023-11-04T11:55:36.846290656Z npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm 806ms (cache updated)

/home/LogFiles/2023_11_04_10-30-8-108_docker.log (https://test-azure-app-node.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2023_11_04_10-30-8-108_docker.log)

2023-11-04T11:57:39.580Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container test-azure-app-node_0_34624557. Elapsed time = 127.0055714 sec

2023-11-04T11:57:54.688Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container test-azure-app-node_0_34624557. Elapsed time = 142.1134705 sec

2023-11-04T11:58:11.276Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container test-azure-app-node_0_34624557. Elapsed time = 158.7012306 sec

2023-11-04T11:58:26.396Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container test-azure-app-node_0_34624557. Elapsed time = 173.8216572 sec

2023-11-04T11:58:41.529Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container test-azure-app-node_0_34624557. Elapsed time = 188.9545469 sec

2023-11-04T11:58:56.701Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container test-azure-app-node_0_34624557. Elapsed time = 204.1264754 sec

2023-11-04T11:59:11.820Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container test-azure-app-node_0_34624557. Elapsed time = 219.2457876 sec

2023-11-04T11:59:22.924Z ERROR - Container test-azure-app-node_0_34624557 for site test-azure-app-node did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.3494381 sec
```

Comment: please share the code and how did you deployed

Comment: @Sampath Please check my edited question, I deployed it with Azure vs code extension, in my folder i right click and did deploy to web app and process start happening

Comment: @Sampath I think the issue is with the port can you tell me how to set port 8080 for running my project?  in Azure app service? how to get the dockerfile

Comment: Have you used docker configuration in local as well? Deployed to azure windows or Linux

Comment: @Sampath i use a Mac but, For azure its deployed on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I have added port 8080 in the code and can deploy it to the Azure web app and see the output.***

***Code :***

```js
const express = require('express');

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080; 
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World");
});

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello, Azure");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server Is Running On Port", port);
});
```

***package.json :***

```json
{
    "name": "my-node-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A simple Node.js app",
    "main": "src/index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node src/index.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "express": "^4.17.1"
    }
  }
```

***Output :***

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

I got the below output with port 8080 in the browser.

[image]

[image]

The above code deployed successfully to the Azure web app as below. Then, I click on **Browse Website** to see the output in the browser.

[image]

**(OR)**

***Azure Portal :***

Click on the **Browse** button in the Azure web app to check the deployment output as below:

[image]

***Browse Output :***

[image]

[image]